# I keep getting this error. How do I fix it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

```
Failed to compile
src\App.js
  Line 2:9:    Replace `BrowserRouter·as·Router,·Route,·Switch` with `·BrowserRouter·as·Router,·Route,·Switch·`  prettier/prettier
  Line 3:1:    Expected exception block, space or tab after '//' in comment                                      spaced-comment
  Line 4:20:   Insert `·`                                                                                        prettier/prettier
  Line 10:1:   Expected exception block, space or tab after '//' in comment                                      spaced-comment
  Line 14:7:   Delete `⏎······`                                                                                  prettier/prettier
  Line 16:1:   Replace `⏎······<NavMenu` with `········<NavMenu·`                                                prettier/prettier
  Line 19:7:   Insert `··`                                                                                       prettier/prettier
  Line 20:1:   Insert `··`                                                                                       prettier/prettier
  Line 21:1:   Replace `··········<About` with `············<About·`                                             prettier/prettier
  Line 22:1:   Insert `··`                                                                                       prettier/prettier
  Line 23:1:   Replace `········` with `··········`                                                              prettier/prettier
  Line 24:11:  Replace `<Projects` with `··<Projects·`                                                           prettier/prettier
  Line 25:1:   Insert `··`                                                                                       prettier/prettier
  Line 26:9:   Insert `··`                                                                                       prettier/prettier
  Line 27:11:  Replace `<Contact` with `··<Contact·`                                                             prettier/prettier
  Line 28:1:   Replace `········` with `··········`                                                              prettier/prettier
  Line 29:1:   Insert `··`                                                                                       prettier/prettier
  Line 30:11:  Replace `<Home` with `··<Home·`                                                                   prettier/prettier
  Line 31:9:   Insert `··`                                                                                       prettier/prettier
  Line 32:1:   Replace `······</Switch>⏎` with `········</Switch>`                                               prettier/prettier

src\components\NavMenu.js
  Line 15:34:  Insert `·`                                        prettier/prettier
  Line 16:1:   Replace `␍⏎····return` with `··return·`           prettier/prettier
  Line 18:1:   Replace `········` with `····`                    prettier/prettier
  Line 19:7:   Delete `······`                                   prettier/prettier
  Line 20:1:   Replace `················` with `········`        prettier/prettier
  Line 21:1:   Delete `··········`                               prettier/prettier
  Line 22:9:   Delete `········`                                 prettier/prettier
  Line 23:1:   Replace `················` with `········`        prettier/prettier
  Line 24:1:   Replace `····················` with `··········`  prettier/prettier
  Line 25:1:   Replace `················` with `········`        prettier/prettier
  Line 26:1:   Replace `················` with `········`        prettier/prettier
  Line 27:1:   Delete `··········`                               prettier/prettier
  Line 28:9:   Delete `········`                                 prettier/prettier
  Line 29:1:   Replace `················` with `········`        prettier/prettier
  Line 30:1:   Delete `··········`                               prettier/prettier
  Line 31:1:   Replace `················` with `········`        prettier/prettier
  Line 32:1:   Delete `······`                                   prettier/prettier
  Line 33:5:   Delete `····`                                     prettier/prettier
  Line 34:3:   Delete `··`                                       prettier/prettier
  Line 35:2:   Insert `␍⏎`                                       prettier/prettier

src\pages\About.js
  Line 1:26:  Insert `;`                            prettier/prettier
  Line 4:3:   Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
  Line 5:1:   Replace `········` with `····`        prettier/prettier
  Line 6:1:   Replace `············` with `······`  prettier/prettier
  Line 7:5:   Delete `····`                         prettier/prettier
  Line 8:3:   Replace `··)` with `);`               prettier/prettier

src\pages\Contact.js
  Line 1:26:  Insert `;`                            prettier/prettier
  Line 4:3:   Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
  Line 5:1:   Replace `········` with `····`        prettier/prettier
  Line 6:1:   Replace `············` with `······`  prettier/prettier
  Line 7:5:   Delete `····`                         prettier/prettier
  Line 8:3:   Replace `··)` with `);`               prettier/prettier

src\pages\Home.js
  Line 4:3:  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
  Line 5:1:  Replace `········` with `····`        prettier/prettier
  Line 6:1:  Replace `············` with `······`  prettier/prettier
  Line 7:5:  Delete `····`                         prettier/prettier
  Line 8:3:  Replace `··)` with `);`               prettier/prettier

src\pages\Projects.js
  Line 1:26:  Insert `;`                            prettier/prettier
  Line 4:3:   Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
  Line 5:1:   Replace `········` with `····`        prettier/prettier
  Line 6:1:   Replace `············` with `······`  prettier/prettier
  Line 7:5:   Delete `····`                         prettier/prettier
  Line 8:3:   Replace `··)` with `);`               prettier/prettier

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Comment: You need to either fix these errors, or [set up rules in `.eslintrc.json`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#configuring-rules) to either turn them into warnings or disable them altogether.

Comment: These are lint issues. Run command `npm run lint -- --fix` to fix them.

Comment: The issue is with LF and CRLF. This might help: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/211#issuecomment-575602403